# How does hydrophilic and/or hydrophobic components of polysaccharides influence their 3 dimensional conformation?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

It is my understanding that polysaccharides are insoluble in water. Does this mean they are hydrophobic? Beyond being insoluble in water how does this affect their 3D structure?

Thanks!